# Word to PDF loses quality of chart

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, printing

If I save (or File-> Export) a .docx document to .pdf, I lose quality of image.
I want to save the file as pdf (instead of printing it to pdf) to retain the bookmarks of the text (from the titles). If I print to pdf, the generated pdf does not have the bookmarks and I don't know where to set it on Word.
(the print to pdf is interesting because I can choose non-contiguous pages to generate the pdf, but I lose the ability to generate the pdf with bookmars - but that is another problem)

The original image is a chart from Excel, that I copied on the body of text in Word.

[image]

The pdf file generates this horrible figure.
[image]

I don't understand why this happens. Why does it happen? Any warkaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably embedded the picture from Excel as a bitmap image
(or a similar format) of a certain
resolution, and are trying to print or display it at a higher resolution.

What you are seeing is the general case of enlarging a bitmap image,
where the pixels themselves become visible as small squares or rectangles.

You should export the image from Excel as `.emf` or `.wmf`, which are formats
of vector images that can be scaled up infinitely.
I don't know what you are doing exactly and so don't know if you will have
that option.

If you are pasting the picture into Word, use the option of
"Paste Special...", found under the icon "Paste" on the ribbon's Home pane,
and choose the option of "Picture (Enhanced Metafile)" (or similar wording).
If you don't see that option, review the way that you are copying the image
from Excel.

Comment: I actually just copied ctrl+C and pasted ctrl+V the chart from Excel to Word.  It probably pasted as a graphic object. I can actually edit some chart properties directly into word, like adding legends, changing colors etc. I though as a chart object it should be a vector image.

Comment: Try to do it again and see if in Paste Special you have the option for other types like emf or wmf.